# Why is $timeout invoking $scope functions in a different Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `current-time` directive using `$timeout`, and it appears to be invoking functions in a separate controller. I'm confused why this is, I thought Controllers contained their own scope and were isolated from each other?,

Basically, `myFunction` is being invoked when the `currentTime` directive `$timeout` occurs. Is it a big deal? Will this cause troubles for me down the road? Can someone help me understand this behavior? Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oIQDS03jkanrGOsRmRlA?p=preview) that demonstrates the behavior I'm talking about.

Here is my `HTML`:

```
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head> <!-- using Angular version 1.2.0-rc3 --> </head>
  <body>

    <div ng-controller="TimeController">
      <span current-time></span>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="MyController">
      <span class="grrr">{{myFunction()}}</span>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My Angular code:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

// just to show that I'm using my currentTime directive in separate controller.
// but it still happens if remove TimeController.
myapp.controller('TimeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  console.log('entering TimeController');
}]);

myapp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.myFunction = function() {
    console.log('calling myFunction');
    return 'myFunction was last called @ ' + new Date().toString();
  };

}]);

// continuous update for time
myapp.directive('currentTime', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

  return function(scope,element,attrs) {
    function updateTime() {
      $timeout(function() {
        element.text(new Date().toString());
        updateTime();
      }, 1000);
    };
    console.log('start clock');
    updateTime();
  };
}]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL:DR;**

Change your directive to

```
    $timeout(function() {
      element.text(new Date().toString());
      updateTime();
    }, 1000, false);
```

And it won't trigger your `myFunction()`

**Long story**

When you do this

```
<span class="grrr">{{myFunction()}}</span>
```

You're basically telling Angular that the contents of the span should always equal the result of calling `myFunction()`.

Now, Angular does not know what kinds of variables your function relies on to return a result, so whenever something changes, it needs to call that function again to see if it returns something else (this is called dirty-checking). Keep this in mind, it will be important once we look at the directive.

In the directive you're running `$timeout` every second. That triggers a `$digest` loop, which is basically Angular's way of detecting if things have changed. In the process of doing that it's checking ALL the scopes, which means it will also be calling your `myFunction()` to see if anything the directive did affected that. That's why it keeps getting called.

Now, if you don't want this behaviour, you could either bind to a variable instead of a function, OR if you're curious like me head over to the sourcecode for [$timeout](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/timeout.js#L52). I suppose you could look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout) as well, but to be honest most of the Angular docs aren't that good so I usually go for the source first.

There's an optional flag (and this one is even documented) called `invokeApply`, if you set it to false then `$timeout` will not trigger dirty-checking.

Answer (score 2):

That is the way that the $digest cycle works.  When a $digest is triggered, angular will loop through all the $watch expressions and determine if they have changed.  This happens for all $watch expressions on all scopes - a process called dirty-checking.

The reason that myFunction() is being called is because you have an implicit $watch on it as a result of the binding expression:

```
{{myFunction()}}
```

This is normal and nothing to be concerned about.

The reason that the $digest cycle is being triggered periodically is because of your $timeout function. By default, it will invoke your timeout function within an $apply block which, in turn, triggers the $digest.  You can disable this behavior by passing false as the third argument to $timeout.

I would like to suggest that you use `$interval` instead of `$timeout`. It is better suited for this.